# Ubuntu 18.04 can't play any video or audio in any browser?

Tags: video, vlc, browser, streaming, media

Suddenly, my Ubuntu 18.04 is not capable of streaming any media online through a browser (any browser).

But I still can play any kind of video through VLC if I download them. I can also stream videos through VLC normally (even youtube videos)

**But even on VLC, there is no sound. Only video.**

I have tried the testing videos located on this link: https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html

I have tried audio on this link
https://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/

And I couldn't play any of them through a browser but I was able to stream them through VLC but without sound.

I have tried all the obvious solutions that I can think of like updating my graphics card driver (which was really out-of-date) and installing the codecs. But my problem has remained exactly the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed KDE in order to see if the problem will persist in there. I found out that in KDE all video and audio playback is working normally.

I then returned to Gnome and to my surprise, everything is working normally there also.

So the problem has been solved.